# Ubuntu 16.04 and Mate Desktop in VNC Session no Keyboard by mythtv-backend

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, vnc, mate, mythtv

I can not use my keyboard in a VNC Session when I open mythtv-backend on mate desktop. The keyboard works in the normal VNC Session but not when I start mythtv-backend or mythtv-frontend. My keyboard preference setting under Ubuntu Mate doesn't work also.

I get the following error by start of mythtv-backend:

```
Qt: XKEYBOARD Extension not present on the X server.
```

Please help me.

Greetings,
Sven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made it with TurboVNC in Version 2.1. Now the keyboard works.